# How to make All div tags responsive by changing their no. of colums

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a simple webpage but When I open a webpage on mobile it looks ugly and all the div containers look huge. so the change I want is when I open this webpage on mobile the number of columns should decrease to 3 and the no. of rows should increase accordingly.
I know I need to use media query but I don't know how to decrease no. of columns. I tried many times but when I decrease it all the containers overlap.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #485461;
background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #485461 0%, #28313b 74%);
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }

  * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  h5 {
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 12px;
 
  }

  .center {
    height: 75vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  /* End Non-Essential  */

  #video,
  #vd,
  #vd1,
  #vd4,
  #vd5,
  #vd6,
  #vd7,
  #vd8 {
    height: 18em;
    width: 14em;
    display: none;
    object-fit: cover
  }

  .property-card {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 18em;
    width: 14em;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    border-radius: 16px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
  }

  /* ^-- The margin bottom is necessary for the drop shadow otherwise it gets clipped in certain cases. */

  /* Top Half of card, image. */

  .property-image {
    height: 15em;
    width: 14em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    position: Absolute;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    background-image: url('https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/What-is-landscape-photography.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  /* Bottom Card Section */

  .property-description {
    background-color: #FAFAFC;
    height: 5em;
    width: 14em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-align: center;
  }

  /* Social Icons */

  .property-social-icons {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  }

  /* Property Cards Hover States */

  .property-card:hover .property-description {
    height: 0em;
    padding: 0px 1em;
  }

  .property-card:hover .property-image {
   
    background-size: cover;

  }

  .property-card:hover .property-social-icons {
    background-color: white;
  }

  .property-card:hover .property-social-icons:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <div class="property-card" id="property-card">
     
        <div onmousedown="f1()"  class="property-image" id="image">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls>
          <source src="saiyaan-video.mp4">
        </video>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
     
      <div onmousedown="f2()"  class="property-image" id="ig">
        <div class="property-image-title"></div>
      </div>
      <video id="vd" width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src="Te amo.mp4">
      </video>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
        <div onmouseover="f3()" class="property-image" id="ig1">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd1">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
        <div onmouseover="f7()" class="property-image" id="ig7">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd7">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="property-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div onmouseover="f4()" class="property-image" id="ig4">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd4">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      </a>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div onmouseover="f5()" class="property-image" id="ig5">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd5">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      </a>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div onmouseover="f6()" class="property-image" id="ig6">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd6">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      </a>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="property-card">
      <a href="#">
        <div onmouseover="f8()" class="property-image" id="ig8">
          <div class="property-image-title"></div>
        </div>
        <video id="vd8">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
      </a>
      <div class="property-description">
        <h5> Card Title </h5>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: What did you try? Can you share the results in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent so that the cards will flow to next row when there is not enough space. You alsi have to remove the `height: 75vh;` from the containers to prevent them from overlapping:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #485461;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #485461 0%, #28313b 74%);
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* End Non-Essential  */

#video,
#vd,
#vd1,
#vd4,
#vd5,
#vd6,
#vd7,
#vd8 {
  height: 18em;
  width: 14em;
  display: none;
  object-fit: cover
}

.property-card {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 18em;
  width: 14em;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 27px #e1e1e3, -15px -15px 27px #ffffff;
}


/* ^-- The margin bottom is necessary for the drop shadow otherwise it gets clipped in certain cases. */


/* Top Half of card, image. */

.property-image {
  height: 15em;
  width: 14em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  position: Absolute;
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  background-image: url('https://cdn.photographylife.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/What-is-landscape-photography.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Bottom Card Section */

.property-description {
  background-color: #FAFAFC;
  height: 5em;
  width: 14em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Social Icons */

.property-social-icons {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}


/* Property Cards Hover States */

.property-card:hover .property-description {
  height: 0em;
  padding: 0px 1em;
}

.property-card:hover .property-image {
  background-size: cover;
}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons {
  background-color: white;
}

.property-card:hover .property-social-icons:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="property-card" id="property-card">
    <div class="property-image" id="image">
      <div class="property-image-title"></div>
    </div>
    <video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls>
          <source src="saiyaan-video.mp4">
        </video>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <div class="property-image" id="ig">
      <div class="property-image-title"></div>
    </div>
    <video id="vd" width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src="Te amo.mp4">
      </video>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <div class="property-image" id="ig1">
      <div class="property-image-title"></div>
    </div>
    <video id="vd1">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <div class="property-image" id="ig7">
      <div class="property-image-title"></div>
    </div>
    <video id="vd7">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="center">
  <div class="property-card">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="property-image" id="ig4">
        <div class="property-image-title"></div>
      </div>
      <video id="vd4">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="property-image" id="ig5">
        <div class="property-image-title"></div>
      </div>
      <video id="vd5">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="property-image" id="ig6">
        <div class="property-image-title"></div>
      </div>
      <video id="vd6">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="property-card">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="property-image" id="ig8">
        <div class="property-image-title"></div>
      </div>
      <video id="vd8">
          <source control src="Pexels Videos 2795749.mp4" type="video/webm">
        </video>
    </a>
    <div class="property-description">
      <h5> Card Title </h5>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum Dipsum hortata. Mixcall Horcho. Mixwell Chingo. More Bingo. Lorem Ipum doth be hard.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As I said they are overlapping each other

Comment: @IndianCoder check updated answer. You have to remove the `height: 75vh;` from the containers. Both of them can't be `75vh` without overlapping each other.

Comment: resize you window to 1034px and then see they are arranged in order of

Comment: * * *  //talking about space

Comment: *    //here is single card

Comment: * * *  // here again it's three

Comment: BUT WHAT I NEED IS

Comment: `1034px`: https://ibb.co/68Bf22Q

You want to remove space at the bottom?

Comment: * * *  /////////

Comment: * * * /////////

Comment: * * * /////////

Comment: when we will decrease width then there should be 3 X4  by default its 4X3

Comment: `3*4 = 12`, you only have `2` containers and with `4` cards with a total of `8`. So I don't understand how you come up with 3*4. You can get `2x (1*3 + 1*1) = 8`